# Yii module only works on localhost but not on sites

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

I have a website where I developed it using Yii bootstrap framework. Then I just want create a comment module where this modules I downloaded it from from Yii (the link is below):

[Comments module link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/comments-module/)

Then I have tested it on my localhost and it works. However the comments modules does not work on my site.

Below is the code for my main:

```
<?php
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../components/Helper.php');

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
Yii::setPathOfAlias('CoverUploadDir', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../uploads/covers');
Yii::setPathOfAlias('ContentsUploadDir', dirname(__FILE__).'/../../uploads/contents');

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'Smart Mobile Library',
'theme' => 'bootstrap',
// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',


),

'modules'=> array( 



'comments'=>array(
        //you may override default config for all connecting models
    'defaultModelConfig' => array(
        //only registered users can post comments
    'registeredOnly' => true,
    'useCaptcha' => true,
        //allow comment tree
    'allowSubcommenting' => true,
        //display comments after moderation
    'premoderate' => false,
        //action for posting comment
    'postCommentAction' => 'comments/comment/postComment',
        //super user condition(display comment list in admin view and automoderate comments)
    'isSuperuser'=>'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()',
     //order direction for comments
    'orderComments'=>'DESC',
    ),

    //the models for commenting
    'commentableModels'=>array(
        //model with individual settings
        'Book'=>array(
            'registeredOnly'=>true,
            'useCaptcha'=>true,
            'allowSubcommenting'=>false,
            //config for create link to view model page(page with comments)
            'pageUrl'=>array(
                'route'=>'/admin/book',
                'data'=>array('id'=>'book_id'),
            ),
        ),
        //model with default settings
    'ImpressionSet',
    ),
    //config for user models, which is used in application
    'userConfig'=>array(
        'class'=>'User',
        'nameProperty'=>'fullname',
        'emailProperty'=>'email',
    ),
),


    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'lovesick',
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        'generatorPaths'=>array(
            'bootstrap.gii',
        ),
    ),



),

// application components
'components'=>array(

    'counter' => array(
         'class' => 'bootstrap.components.UserCounter',
                    ),
    'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',

    ),
    'user'=>array(

        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'class' => 'Admin',
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
    /*
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',


        ),
    ),
    */
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=smartmob_administrators',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'donkey',
        'password' => 'donkey1001',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
    ),
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'admin@smartmobilelibrary.com',
  ),
);
```

I have followed all the guidelines that have been given and i really dont know what is the problem. Whenever i called this alias below

```
 $this->widget('comments.widgets.ECommentsListWidget', array(     'model' => $model, ));
```

it will not show any errors but my page will become white where all of my themes is gone. It just showed the contents and no comments modules. I think there is something wrong with my url manager. i have tried to implement the below codes but still no success

```
'<modules:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:[\w-]+>' => '<modules>/<controller>/<action>',
'<modules:\w+>/<controller:\w+>'                 =>        '<modules>/<controller>',
'<modules:\w+>'                                  => '<modules>',
```

Comment: I think y use wrong alias `comment.views.comment.commentList` it's weird and this path cannot exist. In documentation it says `$this->widget('comments.widgets.ECommentsListWidget', array(
    'model' => $model,
));` and not render.

Comment: owh my mistake... i think i copied it from my other source. I used this alias `$this->widget('comments.widgets.ECommentsListWidget', array(     'model' => $model, ));` and it give me the error that i have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I Have manage to solve this problem after review the error log. The problem is the php version in my site is 5.2 and in my localhost is 5.3. Therefore it is giving me error which is

```
syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM
```

This error is happen due to an extra double colon in `public function getOwnerModel()` in comment models where the error is in line 337 which are as below:
Basically this code below only works in php version 5.3 but not in php5.2

```
$this->_ownerModel = $ownerModel::model()->findByPk($key);
```

Therefore i have changed it to:

```
$model = call_user_func(array($ownerModel, 'model'));
$this->_ownerModel =  $model->findByPk($key);
```